# Deleting specific commits locally

Tags: git

On my local repo I have an origin and upstream remote repositories. Origin is a forked repo or upstream. To update my origin I run the command `git pull --rebase upstream master` and that will make my origin be the same as upstream.
This time its not working. I must have about 7-8 commits that have not been rebased. I am trying to delete them but can't find any ways. I have Googled and looked here but any suggestions I tried just did not work.

I have the workflow A - B - C - D - E, each letter representing a commit on master. I want to remove commits B, C and D. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: https://www.clock.co.uk/insight/deleting-a-git-commit this looks like it might help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have commits A - B - C - D - E. You can use `git rebase -i HEAD~5` (up to the parent of first removed commit - i.e. A), then delete lines with commits you want to remove (leave lines with A and E), then save.

More info on interactive rebase: https://hackernoon.com/beginners-guide-to-interactive-rebasing-346a3f9c3a6d

Comment: Tried something similar yesterday and it didn't work, but worked a treat this morning, thanks